# Hide symfony/var-dumper output in live environment

Tags: symfony, dump

Is there a simple way (via config or env variables) to only show the dump output in dev/staging environment?

Comment: var dumper shouldn't be required in your prod dependencies, it should be in `require-dev`. And you shouldn't leave `dump()` functions in your code, only use it for debugging.

Comment: You have `dump()`s in your codebase? Your code is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

as stated @Iwan, the dump() is the solution.

You can find the result into your Symfony Profiler, in the **Debug** tab :

[image: debug tab]